# Problem with multidimensional array in php/wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
foreach(get_field('color') as $singleColorCP2) {                              
    $new_fields = get_fields($singleColorCP2->ID);
    foreach($new_fields as $name => $value)
        echo $value;
                                  
}
```

this is my code and it is running it prints like,

```
firstfield_valueasecondfield_valuea<br>
firstfield_valuebsecondfield_valueb<br>
firstfield_valuecsecondfield_valuec<br>
```

I'm getting crazy how to print just:

```
firstfield_valuea
firstfield_valueb
firstfield_valuec
```

I'm interested only in one column.

("name" prints the correct name of the field, but still with the same problem, in couple with the second field, I can't divide)

Comment: What are the ACF field types, and what data do you have stored in them?

Comment: 1 table is products

the other one is a set of colors with their thumb. I have also another field in the table "colors" called comment, but I want to extract only the url of the image. I could print with - and explode the string, but I want to find a more direct solution.

Comment: I asked you about the ACF field types, so why are you talking about “tables”? Also, please give an _example_ of that data, instead of just a verbal description.

Comment: because they are like table of a database, same problem. table 1 products  (title, description, color) 2 colors (tile, image, comment) and there is a custom relational field in common that shows all the colors in the custom post products. And obviously you can choose also more colors for the same product. But my problem was about array not about wordpress and I have found a solution, read below.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(get_field('color') as $singleColorCP2) {                              
    $new_fields = get_fields($singleColorCP2->ID);
    foreach($new_fields as $name => $value)
    
  if($name == 'field_name'){
                    $val[] = $value;                                   
                                        }
                                        }
echo $val[0];                                   
echo $val[1];
echo $val[2];
```

I have found this solution in the end...with if. That's not what I would have liked but it works at least and it hasnt much code.